# What program(s) do biologists use for statistics?

Tags: discussion, statistics

I'm trying to get a handle on **what programs different *fields* of biology use to run statistical tests** and other analyses.

- Ex: R, SPSS, SAS, GraphPad / PRISM, MATLAB, Python, MS Excel, PCORD, STATA, etc.

Please answer with:

1. **Your sub-field of biology**
2. **What program you think your field overwhelmingly/generally uses.**

   - i.e., what is the "Standard" program for your field?
3. **What program you use**

If you share a sub-field / standard with an existing answer, please simply vote/comment. Otherwise add a new answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Note: I understand not all analyses are statistical. I want this post, however, to focus on statistical analyses. Programs used for more nuanced non-statistical analyses can be mentioned in the comments or as additional points in your answer.

Comment: I'm just now wondering if this post is inherently biased. I assume (possibly incorrectly) that a large majority of Bio.SE users probably initially joined the SE network for SO (stockOverflow), and so many users here are very likely more programming-software oriented. As such, I wonder if many of our answers (e.g., R and python) are truly accurate for the fields or just popular among biologists with backgrounds with programming-oriented statistics software. [No need to comment; just keep this in mind as you read results].

Answer (score 4):

**Field:** Ecology

**Standard:**  [R](https://www.r-project.org/)

What I use: R

Comment: As a bioinformatician, my experience is that everyone uses R except wet-lab biologists who use Excel.

Comment: @terdon that was my impression, too. But then i started asking around, and some wet-lab folks use Prism. I also know some ecology ppl still using SAS.  That got me to wondering how accurate my (and your) assumptions really are...

Comment: Well, that was a bit tongue-in-cheek. I'm sure nobody who does statistical analyses regularly uses excel. The people I'm thinking of would just use it for a one-off analysis; they're not stats folks at all. That said, neither am I, of course, which is why I like R: it does the work for me.

Comment: @terdon, also if you feel confident about it, please add an answer for bioinformatics.

Comment: I'm a wet-lab biologist and I use R! Not really for stats, though.

Comment: @canadianer interesting. What specifically do you use R for? And what do you use for stats?

Comment: @theforestecologist Mostly analyzing data from experiments on protein binding kinetics, and preparing figures. I guess in some sense "analyzing data" is statistics, but I'm not doing any statistical tests.

Answer (score 3):

**Field:** Bioinformatics (I can speak for genomics, NGS, and systems biology)

**Standard:** [R](https://www.r-project.org/)

What I use: R

Answer (score 3):

Multiple, so here goes. I assume you don't mind them as a single answer?

---

**Field**: Experimental Molecular Biology/Synthetic Biology, & Microbiology

**Standard**: Excel (sadly). If you can afford it, PRISM.

What I use: R and/or Python

---

**Field**: Bioinformatics (Microbial NGS etc.)

**Standard**: R and/or Python (largely taking over from Perl I think)

What I use: R and Python

---

**Field**: Structural Bioinformatics

**Standard**: Python + C (usually in the form of bespoke software though, e.g. PyMOL)

What I use: Python

Comment: Prism!! Yes!! I love that software.

Comment: Shame more Institutions won't shell out for a license :(

Comment: I bought a license for my previous postdoc. My current institution has a license :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Field**: Phylogeny

Disclaimer: I'm not active in phylogeny any more (I was until 2013), and I didn't use statistics very often.

**Standard**: I think that statistical tests part of phylogeny inference procedures tend to be implemented in specific phylogeny reconstruction programs. These are usually written in fast languages (usually C/C++, but I know at least a case using OCaml). I've seen also statistical tests in a Python based package (possibly with C/C++ underlying stuff), and I heard about R packages for phylogeny handling.

What I use(d): Python (`scipy.stats`)

Answer (score 1):

**Field:** Microbial Bioprocesses/White Biotechnologies

**Standard:** Excel or R

What I use: Excel, R or Python

Answer (score 1):

**Field**: Neuroscience

**Standard**: Matlab

**What I use**: Matlab

Answer (score 1):

Field: models of the transmission of infectious disease

Standard: Matlab, R

What I use: Matlab, Fortran.